# Zurb Orbit: add text over images

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, orbit

I would to add a Title and Description foreach slide, something like this:

[image]

```
  <!-- Header -->
  <div id="featured">
      <img src="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w780/fI3ucpgaVKOUcQ82vhgWmWuLlg2.jpg">
      <img  src="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w780/dAc3Ob868XGnAX8uOptb7HWx0In.jpg">
      <img  src="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w780/2fwHVLvh6kdwCujsMwtNmwRJAf1.jpg">   
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {

       $('#featured').orbit();
    });
  </script>
```

I've tried with "captions" but I don't get the same effect. How I could do?

[Zurb Fondation Orbit](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/orbit.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am working with Foundation right now so I will try to help you with it. Since I haven't done this before your feedback will be helpful.

First in your App.js add this line for a Fluid Orbit:

```
$('#featuredContent').orbit({ fluid: '800x800' });
```

800x800 is your Orbit Slider Width and Height.

Then in your App.css you would add this:

```
#featuredContent .back {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Which referes to your #featuredContent in your .js file and adds a .back class which we will use in our HTML code:

```
<div id="featuredContent">
  <div>
    <h4>This is a content slider.</h4>
    <p>Each slide holds arbitrary content, like text or actions.</p>
    <img class="back" src="/images/test.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>We can include text and buttons, like this!</h4>
    <p>We take no responsibility for what happens if you click this button.</p>
    <p><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" class="button" target="_blank">Rock My World!</a></p>
    <img class="back" src="/images/test.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>We can include text and buttons, like this!</h4>
    <p>We take no responsibility for what happens if you click this button.</p>
    <p><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" class="button" target="_blank">Rock My World!</a></p>
    <img class="back" src="/images/test.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I guess this should do the trick and have the picture in the background with a title (H4) and a description (P) under it. You could also customize the position of the title and description in the css using:

```
#featuredContent p {
}
```

and

```
#featuredContent h4 {
}
```